# Focus on text input in Google Chrome on Windows Server 2012 causes Windows Explorer to open?

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a weird situation here. I have an Amazon EC2 instance running Windows Server 2012. I installed Google Chrome on the volume. Everything works fine but one very annoying thing. When I'm using Google Chrome if I click on the address bar or any text input Windows Explorer pops up to a folder with the path C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\XX.XX.XX.XX\ (these X's seem to be in the format of an IP address). Has anyone else ran into this and if so what is going on and is there a fix? Everything works fine, but it's just annoying me for this window to pop up. Thanks

Comment: I am having the same problem too, launching in Windows 7 compatibility mode seems to work but you loose the multi-touch support etc. The X's are the build version not IP address.

Comment: This issue can be reproduced in the iOS Microsoft Remote Desktop App in touch mode, mouse mode works fine.